# Angular UI Mask for SSN on blur

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

Im using angular-ui-mask for SSN, the initial ui-mask is "999-99-9999", but on blur I need to display the SSN 123-45-6789 characters as XXX-XX-6789.

I tried setting ui-mask as XXX-XX-9999 but it's showing the first 4 digits of the SSN at the end of 'XXX-XX-' instead of the last four digits.

Here's the HTML Code

```
<input class="btnDropdown" id="phoneTextInput" ui-mask="{{uimaskpattern}}" ui-mask-placeholder-char=""
  ng-focus="applymask()"
  ng-blur="removemask(contact.contactDetails.attributeDetails.contact)"

  md-minlength="10" md-maxlength="10" name="Phone_{{$index}}" ng-model="contact"
  placeholder="">
```

Here's the Typescript code

```
public applymask() {
    this.uimaskpattern = "999-99-9999";

}

public removemask(ssn, ev) {
    if (ssn) {
        console.log(ssn);
        this.uimaskpattern = "AAA-AA-9999";
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide some code and we'll be able to help you a little further.

Comment: `angular-ui-mask` is not the library you are looking for - that sets an *input mask* to limit what a user can type on an input field

Comment: What can be used for this case? My requirement is to as user enters the digits  '-' should get applied automatically, so that string becomes of format 123-45-6789, and when the user movies out to another field, the input should show XXX-XX-6789

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for jQuery called [jquery.maskedinput](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.maskedinput) that might be of help here.

You can use this plugin to mask the input by creating a custom directive and invoking the library within it. Here's a working example that should mask the input when the input field loses focus:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.ssn = '';
});

app.directive("ssnMasker", function () {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
            $(elem).mask("999-99-9999");  // 9 represents a numeric character in this library
            var temp;
            var regxa = /^(\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4})$/;  // regex to define formatting for a SSN
            
            $(elem).focusin(function () {
                $(elem).val(temp);
            });
            
            $(elem).on("blur",function () {
                temp = $(elem).val();
                if (regxa.test($(elem).val())) {  // check for match
                   $(elem).val("XXX-XX" + temp.slice(6));  // change displayed value
               }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/master/src/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    Type SSN: <input type="text" ng-model="ssn" ssn-masker >
    <p>Actual SSN: {{ ssn }} </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i needed a solution that doesn't uses jQuery

Comment: Then you're probably going to want to look into AngularJS `$parsers` and `$formatters`. Here's a fiddle that might help: https://fiddle.jshell.net/V6GN5/8/light/ Also note that, as mentioned by @JaromandaX, `angular-ui-mask` is basically used to ensure the user can only provide input in a predefined format. By itself it doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This might also be an approach to try - although it's Angular 1.x style - so there's probably a more current / Angular 2 way to do this.

```
HTML     
<input type="text"
       ng-model="data.ssnDisplay"
       ng-blur="blurFunction()">

JAVASCRIPT
// on page load
if (newUser === true) {
    $scope.data.ssn = ''
}
else {
// would normally be delivered via a service endpoint (hard coded here)
    $scope.data.ssn = '123456789'
}

// create display-only property
$scope.data.ssnDisplay = $scope.data.ssn;

// on blur, update display-only property
$scope.blurFunction = function () {
    $scope.data.ssnDisplay = 'XXXXX' + $scope.data.ssn.substring(5);
}

// always maintain primary ssn value - you'll need this when
// posting/saving your data back to your database
$scope.$watch("data.ssnDisplay", function () {
    $scope.data.ssn = $scope.data.ssnDisplay;
})
```

Comment: ng-model doesn't accept values with '-' cause of ui-mask

Comment: Ah - gotcha.  Makes sense.  I wonder if there's a way to use still use the strategy above and just manage the '-' characters differently.  I updated my example above to remove the hard-coded '_' characters.